# Jquery mouseover doesn't work with sprite animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, mouseover

I cant give to work mouseover.

I want move a div in some location and make some div interaction with mouseover, mouseclick and with drag and drop. But, im blocked, becouse, the first step, mouse over, dont like work.
that is the code:

```
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#dxani").mouseover(function() { $("#dxani").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/fr1.png)") });
        $('#dxani').sprite({fps: 3, no_of_frames: 4})
        $("#dxani").animate({marginLeft: "+=200px", }, 20000 );
        setTimeout(function() {$("#dxani").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/sprite1sx.png)")} , 20000 );
        $("#dxani").animate({marginLeft: "-=200px", }, 20000 );
        setTimeout(function() {$("#dxani").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/sprite1dx.png)")} , 40000 );
        $("#dxani").animate({marginLeft: "+=400px", }, 40000 );
        setTimeout(function() {$("#dxani").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/sprite1sx.png)")} , 80000 );
        $("#dxani").animate({marginLeft: "-=400px", }, 40000 );
        setTimeout(function() {$("#dxani").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/sprite1dx.png)")} , 120000 );
        $("#dxani").animate({marginLeft: "+=800px", }, 80000 ); 
        setTimeout(function() {$("#dxani").css("background-image", "url(img/sprite/sprite1dx.png)")} , 200000 );
        $("#dxani").animate({marginLeft: "-=800px", }, 200000 );    



        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly are you getting any error ? share your markup too.

Comment: What do you want to do? Your animate- and timeout-statements look very odd, btw - you know you can (and should) pass callbacks to `.animate()`?

Comment: u can see work here:  http://www.superbau.altervista.org/  i want make some action when i go over, click or drag over element in botton of screen.. the small walking sprite...

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `background-position` values if sprite is to show different areas

Comment: i dont understand, can u explane morE?